# Merge several rows into a single row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation, cisco

I would like to merge several rows into a single row using Excel. I have already done this with the CONCATENATE function but this time I need to automate the process since I have several entries on the file. 
I have the Ephone IP phone information extracted from a Cisco CME where each ephone information is on a row as follows:

```
ephone-1[0] Mac: TCP socket:[57] activeLine:0 whisperLine:0 REGISTERED in SCCP ver 20/17 max_streams=1
mediaActive:0 whisper_mediaActive:0 startMedia:0 offhook:0 ringing:0 reset:0 reset_sent:0 paging 0 debug:0 caps:8 
IP:---------- * 35419 6941  keepalive 54113 max_line 4 available_line 4
button 1: cw:1 ccw:(0 0) 
dn 1  number ------- CH1   IDLE         CH2   IDLE         shared 
Preferred Codec: g711ulaw 
Lpcor Type: none Username: ---- Password: ------ 


ephone-2[1] Mac:-------- TCP socket:[77] activeLine:0 whisperLine:0 REGISTERED in SCCP ver 20/17 max_streams=1
mediaActive:0 whisper_mediaActive:0 startMedia:0 offhook:0 ringing:0 reset:0 reset_sent:0 paging 0 debug:0 caps:8 
IP:------- * 35189 6941  keepalive 117528 max_line 4 available_line 4
button 1: cw:1 ccw:(0 0) 
 dn 2  number ------ CH1   IDLE         CH2   IDLE         shared 
Preferred Codec: g711ulaw 
Lpcor Type: none
```

Each ephone is separated by one or two empty rows on the file. There are around 350 entries and I would like to automate the process. The process should be something like taking each line of the ephone and merge it into a single line, so that at the end I would  have 350 lines containing the info of the 350 ephones.

Does anyone know how to make this on Excel? I would really appreciate the help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do it, consolidating up, and removing excess lines

```
Sub ConsolidateRows_NoMatch()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one

    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 0 Then
        If Left(Cells(i, 1), 6) <> "ephone" Then
            Cells(i - 1, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) & Cells(i, 1)
        Else
            GoTo nxti:
        End If
    End If

    Rows(i).Delete
nxti:
Next

With application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank nutsch for your rapid response. The code is working really good. thank you very much